# Little's Law + Kingman's Formula --> Approximation of Expected Length of G/G/1?

Tags: approximation, queueing

[Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) gives us

$$\mathbb{E}[L] = \lambda \mathbb{E}[W]$$

where

- $L$ is the number of customers in the queue + being served
- $\lambda$ is the arrival rate
- $\mu$ is the service rate
- $W$ is the wait time of a customer from when they arrive to when they finish service.

[Kingman's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingman%27s_formula) states that

$$\mathbb{E}[W] \approx \frac{\rho}{2 (1 - \rho) \mu} \left[ \left( \frac{\text{Var}[A]}{\mathbb{E}[A]} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\text{Var}[S]}{\mathbb{E}[S]} \right)^2 \right]$$

where

- $\rho := \frac{\lambda}{\mu}$ is the utilization
- $A$ is the arrival time
- $S$ is the service time

It seems by a simple substitution I can achieve a related approximation of the number of customers in the system:

$$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[L] &\approx  \frac{\rho \lambda}{2 (1 - \rho) \mu} \left[ \left( \frac{\text{Var}[A]}{\mathbb{E}[A]} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\text{Var}[S]}{\mathbb{E}[S]} \right)^2 \right] \\ & \approx \frac{\rho^2}{2 (1 - \rho)} \left[ \left( \frac{\text{Var}[A]}{\mathbb{E}[A]} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\text{Var}[S]}{\mathbb{E}[S]} \right)^2 \right] \end{align}$$

Clearly Little's law does not assume second moments exist, while Kingman's formula assumes that the arrival and service times have second moments. But beyond that, does this approximation hold?

Comment: Another option is [Lindley equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindley_equation), but I am not interested in that in this question... Unless it indicates the approximation doesn't hold.